# How to convert a complex HTML table which includes rowspan and colspan to JSON, in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, html-table

I am actually working on extracting the Arabic cells from this [Wiktionary table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8#Arabic). The working code is at the end of this post, with zero dependencies, in a simplified form that doesn't use Arabic but simulates the table's complexity to some degree. (In case you can't find the table on Wiktionary, it's hidden behind a toggle right here on the site:)

---

[image]

---

My **one** question is, how can you convert this HTML table, which contains many a `rowspan` and `colspan`, into JSON? Ideally I am looking for a general solution, to account for any combination of rowspans/colspans, not something hardcoded to this specific table layout.

**Expected output**:

The ideal JSON, which I have fully hand-crafted, is as follows. Each "key" in the JSON is a concatentation of all the headers used to define a current cell/block, and the value is the expected cell text (just the Latin text, not the Arabic script text):

```
const rows = [
  {
    "verbal noun": "a",
  },
  {
    "active participle": "b",
  },
  {
    "passive participle": "c",
  },
  {
    "active voice / singular / 1st person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "d",
    "active voice / singular / 2nd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "e",
    "active voice / singular / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "f",
    "active voice / dual / 2nd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "g",
    "active voice / dual / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "h",
    "active voice / plural / 1st person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "i",
    "active voice / plural / 2nd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "j",
    "active voice / plural / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo":
      "k",
  },
  {
    "active voice / singular / 1st person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "d",
    "active voice / singular / 2nd person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "l",
    "active voice / singular / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "m",
    "active voice / dual / 2nd person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "g",
    "active voice / dual / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "n",
    "active voice / plural / 1st person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "i",
    "active voice / plural / 2nd person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "o",
    "active voice / plural / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / bar":
      "p",
  },
];
```

**Notice**:

The multiple top-level and side-level "headers" are concatenated with a `/` slash, like `active voice / dual / 3rd person / past (perfect) indicative / foo`. It then points to the value in that table cell block. But the trick is, it has to account for `rowspan` and `colspan`.

**Attempts**:

My first attempt was to try and actually insert into the DOM the right `td` and `th` cells, according to what the rowspan/colspan said, but that resulted in some very weird and hard to debug behavior. So now I tried to do this with pure JSON calculations. Here is the final code that runs with zero dependencies on the outside web:

```js
const records = normalizeTables()
console.log(JSON.stringify(records, null, 2))

function normalizeTables() {
  const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

  const records = []

  const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table')
  for (const table of tables) {
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr')

    let rowI = 0
    for (const row of rows) {
      records[rowI] ??= []
      // 1. Normalize rowspan by creating rows for each
      let block = row.firstElementChild
      let blockI = 0
      let blockElI = 0
      while (block) {
        const text = block.textContent.trim()
        const type = block.tagName === "TH" ? "heading" : "block";
        records[rowI][blockI] ??= { type, text }
        blockI++;

        if (block.getAttribute('rowspan')) {
          let count = parseInt(block.getAttribute("rowspan"));
          // records[rowI][blockI].count = count
          let nRowI = rowI + 1;
          while (count > 1) {
            records[nRowI] ??= []
            records[nRowI++][blockI] = { type, text };
            count--;
          } 
        }

        if (block.getAttribute("colspan")) {
          let count = parseInt(block.getAttribute("colspan"));
          while (count > 1) {
            records[rowI][blockI++] = { type, text };
            count--;
          }
        }
        
        block = block.nextElementSibling
        blockElI++;
      }

      rowI++
    }
  }

  return records;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">verbal noun</th>
      <td colspan="7">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">active participle</th>
      <td colspan="7">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">passive participle</th>
      <td colspan="7">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="12">active voice</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th colspan="3">singular</th>
      <th rowspan="12"></th>
      <th colspan="2">dual</th>
      <th rowspan="12"></th>
      <th colspan="3">plural</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th>1 <sup>st</sup> person </th>
      <th>2 <sup>nd</sup> person </th>
      <th>3 <sup>rd</sup> person </th>
      <th>2 <sup>nd</sup> person </th>
      <th>3 <sup>rd</sup> person </th>
      <th>1 <sup>st</sup> person </th>
      <th>2 <sup>nd</sup> person </th>
      <th>3 <sup>rd</sup> person </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">past (perfect) indicative</th>
      <th>foo</th>
      <td rowspan="2">d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td rowspan="2">g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td rowspan="2">i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>bar</th>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>p</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note**:

Where I got to wasn't quite to the level of concatenating headers with the `/` slash, I am at the step right before that (probably working in the wrong direction ). Instead, my semi-working example never could figure out how to properly manage and deal with each `rowspan` and `colspan` to propagate them properly. I thought I should have a "normalize step", essentially creating an equal-row-equal-column matrix from the arbitrary colspan/rowspan table. That is, I would create a matrix so each row had the same number of columns (at least in JSON, not using the DOM mutation approach I alluded to earlier), and then from that JSON, I could generate the final output as I described above.

How can this be done? Achieving the **expected output** I posted earlier? The hard part is figuring out how to *propagate* the `rowspan` and `colspan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the idea to turn the table into a normalised matrix having a fixed number of columns and rows, "unmerging" the cells with `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes, duplicating values where needed.

We can distinguish the "qualifier" cells from "data" cells by the use of `td` and `th` tags. In general, the rows that have data, are expected to have that data *after* any qualifier cells, so we could register at which index the data starts in a row.

Here is an implementation:

```js
// Cleaner to remove Arabic text and keep transcriptions
const clean = (txt) => txt.replace(/[\u0600-\u06FF]+/gu, "").trim();

// Converts a HTML table to a matrix, duplicating data where col/rowspans occur
function toMatrix(table) {
    let cells;
    return Array.from(table.rows, row => {
        const buff = Array.from(row.cells, cell =>
            Array.from({length: cell.getAttribute("colspan") ?? 1}, () => ({
                data: cell.tagName == "TD", 
                txt: clean(cell.textContent), 
                span: +(cell.getAttribute("rowspan") ?? 1)
            }))
        ).flat();
        cells = cells?.map(cell => --cell.span ? cell : buff.shift() ?? ({span:1}))
              ?? buff;
        // First entry is an index indicating where the data begins (after qualifiers)
        return [cells.findIndex(cell => cell.data),...cells.map(cell => cell.txt)];
    });
}

// Convert matrix to the desired flat object
function toObject(matrix) {
    const result = {};
    const colQualifiers = [];
    let data = false;
    for (const [dataAt, ...row] of matrix) {
        if (dataAt < 1) { // No data; so this is a heading with column qualifiers
            if (data) colQualifiers.length = 0;
            data = false;
            row.forEach((col, i) => (colQualifiers[i] ??= []).push(col));
        } else { // data
            // From column qualifiers (headers), remove those that do not have data
            if (!data) colQualifiers.splice(0, dataAt); 
            data = true;
            // For sections that have no column headers, create one dummy column qualifier
            if (!colQualifiers.length) colQualifiers[0] = [];
            // Because the first section in the table has qualifiers 
            //    spanning multiple columns, remove duplicates
            const rowQualifier = [...new Set(row.splice(0, dataAt))];
            colQualifiers.forEach((colQualifier, i) => {
                if (row[i]) result[[...colQualifier, ...rowQualifier].join(" / ")] = row[i];
            });
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Run the 2-step conversion on the HTML table in the current document
const matrix = toMatrix(document.querySelector("table"));
const obj = toObject(matrix);
console.log(obj);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td, th { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">verbal noun</th>
      <td colspan="7">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">active participle</th>
      <td colspan="7">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">passive participle</th>
      <td colspan="7">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="12">active voice</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th colspan="3">singular</th>
      <th rowspan="12"></th>
      <th colspan="2">dual</th>
      <th rowspan="12"></th>
      <th colspan="3">plural</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th>1 <sup>st</sup> person </th>
      <th>2 <sup>nd</sup> person </th>
      <th>3 <sup>rd</sup> person </th>
      <th>2 <sup>nd</sup> person </th>
      <th>3 <sup>rd</sup> person </th>
      <th>1 <sup>st</sup> person </th>
      <th>2 <sup>nd</sup> person </th>
      <th>3 <sup>rd</sup> person </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">past (perfect) indicative</th>
      <th>foo</th>
      <td rowspan="2">d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td rowspan="2">g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td rowspan="2">i</td>
      <td>j</td>
      <td>k</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>bar</th>
      <td>l</td>
      <td>m</td>
      <td>n</td>
      <td>o</td>
      <td>p</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I added the `clean` function so I could also easily test it on the table on the Wiktionary page.

Comment: Alright! Amazing stuff, I was stuck at this forever. Not I got some data :) `{"latin":"tujlasī","arabic":"تُجْلَسِي","voice":"passive","plurality":"singular","person":2,"mood":"subjunctive","gender":"female"}`.