# How to parse the French Wiktionary verb conjugation table (quite complex HTML table) to JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, web-scraping, html-table

Building off of [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206795/how-to-convert-a-complex-html-table-which-includes-rowspan-and-colspan-to-json/76212939#76212939) to my last problem (parsing a simplified table based on a Wiktionary table), I have now encountered an even more complicated HTML table which I am having trouble parsing.

The goal is to parse the HTML table to JSON, which includes many rowspan, colspan, and funkiness like using `th[style="background:x"]` to organize the data. It is quite tricky, but the algorithm provided from the linked answer is a huge jumping off point for getting to a solution, I am not sure if it needs to be extended or just tweaked slightly, so still tinkering with that.

But here is what I have hacked on top of that solution:

```js
console.log(parseTableToJSON(document.querySelector("table")));

// Cleaner to remove French text and keep transcriptions
function getData(el) {
  const text = el.textContent.trim();
  if (!text || text === "—") {
    return {};
  }
  if (el.tagName === "TH") {
    return {
      latin: el.textContent.trim(),
    };
  } else if (el.classList.contains("alias")) {
    return {
      alias: el.textContent.trim(),
    };
  } else {
    const wordEls = el.querySelectorAll('*[lang="fr"]');
    const map = {};
    for (const wordEl of wordEls) {
      map[wordEl.textContent.trim()] = true;
    }

    const words = Object.keys(map);

    if (!words.length) {
      words.push(el.textContent.trim());
    }

    const ipas = el.querySelectorAll(".IPA");
    const ipasText = [];
    for (const ipa of ipas) {
      ipasText.push(ipa.textContent.trim().replace(/[\[\]\/]/g, ""));
    }

    return {
      ipa: ipasText,
      french: words,
    };
  }
}

// Converts a HTML table to a matrix, duplicating data where col/rowspans occur
function toMatrix(table) {
  let cells;
  return Array.from(table.rows, (row) => {
    const buff = Array.from(row.cells, (cell) =>
      Array.from({ length: cell.getAttribute("colspan") ?? 1 }, () => ({
        data: cell.tagName == "TD",
        content: getData(cell),
        span: +(cell.getAttribute("rowspan") ?? 1),
      }))
    ).flat();
    cells =
      cells?.map((cell) =>
        --cell.span ? cell : buff.shift() ?? { span: 1 }
      ) ?? buff;
    // First entry is an index indicating where the data begins (after qualifiers)
    return [
      cells.findIndex((cell) => cell.data),
      ...cells.map((cell) => cell.content),
    ];
  });
}

// Convert matrix to the desired flat object
function toObject(matrix) {
  const result = {};
  const colQualifiers = [];
  let data = false;
  for (const [dataAt, ...row] of matrix) {
    if (dataAt < 1) {
      // No data; so this is a heading with column qualifiers
      if (data) colQualifiers.length = 0;
      data = false;
      row.forEach((col, i) => (colQualifiers[i] ??= []).push(col));
    } else {
      // data
      // From column qualifiers (headers), remove those that do not have data
      if (!data) colQualifiers.splice(0, dataAt);
      data = true;
      // For sections that have no column headers, create one dummy column qualifier
      if (!colQualifiers.length) colQualifiers[0] = [];
      // Because the first section in the table has qualifiers
      //    spanning multiple columns, remove duplicates
      const rowQualifier = [...new Set(row.splice(0, dataAt))];
      colQualifiers.forEach((colQualifier, i) => {
        if (row[i])
          result[
            [
              ...colQualifier.map((c) => c.latin),
              ...rowQualifier.map((r) => r.latin),
            ].join(" / ")
          ] = row[i];
      });
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function normalizeTable(table) {
  const plurality = findByText(table, "th", /singular/i).closest("tr");
  const first = findByText(table, "th", /first/i).closest("tr");

  const els = table.querySelectorAll('th[style="background:#DEDEDE"]');

  for (const el of els) {
    const newEl = document.createElement("td");
    newEl.setAttribute("rowspan", el.getAttribute("rowspan"));
    newEl.setAttribute("colspan", el.getAttribute("colspan"));
    newEl.classList.add("alias");
    newEl.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
    el.replaceWith(newEl);
  }

  const ind = table.querySelector('*[title="indicatif"]').closest("tr");

  const inds = ind.querySelectorAll("th");
  for (const ind of inds) {
    ind.textContent = "indicative";
  }

  const sub = table.querySelector('*[title="subjonctif"]').closest("tr");

  sub.parentNode.insertBefore(plurality.cloneNode(true), sub);
  sub.parentNode.insertBefore(first.cloneNode(true), sub);

  const subjs = sub.querySelectorAll("th");

  for (const subj of subjs) {
    subj.textContent = "subjunctive";
  }

  const imprt = table.querySelector('*[title="impératif"]').closest("tr");

  imprt.parentNode.insertBefore(plurality.cloneNode(true), imprt);
  imprt.parentNode.insertBefore(first.cloneNode(true), imprt);

  const imprtvs = imprt.querySelectorAll("th");
  for (const imp of imprtvs) {
    imp.textContent = "imperative";
  }
}

function parseTableToJSON(table) {
  normalizeTable(table);

  const matrix = toMatrix(table);
  const obj = toObject(matrix);

  return obj;
}

function findByText(scope, selector, text) {
  const els = scope.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (const el of els) {
    if (el.textContent.match(text)) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="background:#e2e4c0">
        <span title="infinitif">infinitive</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="1" style="background:#e2e4c0">
        <small>simple</small>
      </th>
      <td>acculer </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" style="background:#e2e4c0">
        <small>compound</small>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="background:#DEDEDE">
        <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2" style="background:#e2e4c0">
        <span title="participe présent">present participle</span> or <span title="">gerund</span>
        <sup>1</sup>
      </th>
      <th colspan="1" style="background:#e2e4c0">
        <small>simple</small>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr ppr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculant</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɑ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" style="background:#e2e4c0">
        <small>compound</small>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="background:#DEDEDE">
        <i>
          <span>ayant</span>
        </i> + past participle
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2"></th>
      <th colspan="3" style="background:#C0C0C0">singular </th>
      <th colspan="3" style="background:#C0C0C0">plural </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#C0C0C0;">first </th>
      <th style="background:#C0C0C0;">second </th>
      <th style="background:#C0C0C0;">third </th>
      <th style="background:#C0C0C0;">first </th>
      <th style="background:#C0C0C0;">second </th>
      <th style="background:#C0C0C0;">third </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4" colspan="2">
        <span title="indicatif">indicative</span>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">je (j’) </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">tu </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">il, elle, on </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">nous </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">vous </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">ils, elles </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" style="background:#c0cfe4">
        <small>(simple <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">
        <span title="présent">present</span>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|s|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|s|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accules</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|s|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|p|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculons</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|p|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.le/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|p|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculent</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">
        <span title="imparfait">imperfect</span>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|s|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculais</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|s|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculais</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|s|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculait</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|p|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculions</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.ljɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|p|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculiez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lje/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|p|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculaient</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" style="background:#c0cfe4">
        <small>(compound <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">
        <span title="passé composé">present perfect</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="background:#DEDEDE">present indicative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#c0cfe4">
        <span title="plus-que-parfait">pluperfect</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="background:#DEDEDE">imperfect indicative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0" colspan="2">
        <span title="subjonctif">subjunctive</span>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">que je (j’) </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">que tu </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">qu’il, qu’elle </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">que nous </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">que vous </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">qu’ils, qu’elles </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" style="background:#c0e4c0">
        <small>(simple <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">
        <span title="subjonctif présent">present</span>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|s|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|s|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accules</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|s|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|p|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculions</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.ljɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|p|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculiez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lje/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|p|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculent</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0" rowspan="1">
        <span title="subjonctif imparfait">imperfect</span>
        <sup>2</sup>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|s|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculasse</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.las/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|s|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculasses</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.las/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|s|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculât</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.la/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|p|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculassions</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.la.sjɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|p|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculassiez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.la.sje/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 3|p|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculassent</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.las/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" style="background:#c0e4c0">
        <small>(compound <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">
        <span title="subjonctif passé">past</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="background:#DEDEDE">present subjunctive of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#c0e4c0">
        <span title="subjonctif plus-que-parfait">pluperfect</span>
        <sup>2</sup>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" style="background:#DEDEDE">imperfect subjunctive of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" style="background:#e4d4c0">
        <span title="impératif">imperative</span>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0">– </th>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0">
        <s>tu</s>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0">– </th>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0">
        <s>nous</s>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0">
        <s>vous</s>
      </th>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0">– </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0" colspan="2">
        <span title="">simple</span>
      </th>
      <td>— </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|s|impr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>— </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 1|p|impr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculons</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="Latn form-of lang-fr 2|p|impr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="color:#7F7F7F">
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.le/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>— </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="background:#e4d4c0" colspan="2">
        <span title="">compound</span>
      </th>
      <td>— </td>
      <th style="background:#DEDEDE">simple imperative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
      <td>— </td>
      <th style="background:#DEDEDE">simple imperative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
      <th style="background:#DEDEDE">simple imperative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
      <td>— </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Some notes:

- It takes advantage of the `background` CSS style to determine which rows have content but are using the `th` header tag. These special rows "alias" their cell content to somewhere else (irrelevant for this post). I gave these elements an `alias` class so I could skip the parsing of their content down the road.
- The `getData` function is what pulls out the appropriate stuff from the "cells", I haven't got around to cleanly abstracting this out yet. If the cell is blank, it returns a blank object. If it is a header, it returns a `{ latin: '...' }` object (latin script). If it is an alias, it returns `{ alias: '...' }`, otherwise it returns the french words/content for the cell.
- Then it starts to get hacky. I tried to normalize the HTML table by cloning the "singlular/plural" and "first/second/third" headers to each sub-section, but that doesn't seem to be working. One of the problems is the initial linked solution doesn't seem to allow for multiple layers of top-down headers, not totally sure about that yet.

The end result should be like the last question, where the **key** (to a JSON object) is the path of all the headers leading up to the cell, and the value is the cell object data. Here is a partial but exact output, there is a bit of content to copy over and don't want to distract from the point.

```
const output = {
  "infinitive / simple": { french: ["acculer"] },
  "infinitive / compound": { alias: "avoir + past participle" },
  "present participle or gerund / simple": {
    french: ["acculant"],
    ipa: ["a.ky.lɑ̃"],
  },
  "present participle or gerund / compound": {
    alias: "ayant + past participle",
  },
  "indicative / (simpletenses) / present / singular / first": {
    french: ["accule"],
    ipa: ["a.kyl"],
  },
  "indicative / (simpletenses) / present / singular / second": {
    french: ["accules"],
    ipa: ["a.kyl"],
  },
  // ...
};
```

The order of the top-headers vs. left-headers can be either way, like these:

- `indicative / (simpletenses) / present / singular / second`
- `singular / second / indicative / (simpletenses) / present`

Doesn't matter to me. This example comes from [this French Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acculer#French), it is a lot more complicated than most of the other language Wiktionary conjugation tables I've seen, but hoping to see if this one is parsable to JSON, without necessarily mutating the DOM in this hacky way like I've resorted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some observations I used to extend the function:

- When a qualifier starts in the first column and there is no *data* in that same row, this should be interpreted as the start of a next section in the table and the qualifier applies to that whole section. So we have three "levels" of qualifiers and the data itself:

  1. Table qualifier: this is a row that has a qualifier in the very first column (likely spanning a few more columns), which applies to all of the rows below it -- until a next table qualifier is encountered

     - If a table qualifier is immediately followed by data rows, the column qualifiers that were previously encountered, will still apply to the data rows that follow
  2. Column qualifier: this is a cell in column headers, and applies to all the data in that same column (or columns, if it is a cell with colspan)
  3. Row qualifier: this is a qualifier in the same row as the data to which it applies. Such qualifiers come in the columns *before* the columns with data
  4. Data are the cells that have the desired information (language rendering, conjucation, inclination,...) for the qualifiers that apply to those cells.
- The `lang` attribute can be used as property in the target objects, so `fr` in the current case and `ar` in the previous question's case.

#### Remarks

- I would structure the output a bit differently. Concatenating identifiers with "/" to build a key seems not an ideal solution. In your more recent question you suggested to use separate keys with value `true`: this is an improvement. Alternatively you could put those identifiers in an array and assign it to a single key called `qualifier`. I went for that.
- Wiktionary is dynamic and edited by different people. We cannot expect that the tables on those pages are perfectly harmonised across different articles, or are structured with web-scraping in mind. Where the structure of these tables is less optimal or clearly deviates from what should be expected, it would probably be better to *edit* the page than to try to work around those issues through coding.
- The solution I present below will only work for a few tables, notably the ones for Arabic, Latin, French and Ancient Greek. In light of potential wiki edits I can of course not guarantee that this will keep working as intended in the future.

When comparing the tables for [French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acculer#French), [Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrenuntio#Latin), [Arabic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8#Arabic) and [Ancient Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CE%BC%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%80%CF%84%CF%89#Ancient_Greek), I found there were many problems/inconsistencies on those pages, including:

- Little clue is given for identifying which cells have what you call an "alias" (a notion that only occurs in the table for French). The background color is specific, but I would use that as a last resort. Call me stubborn, but I chose to use the `i > span` selector to identify these entries. It would have been better if a specific CSS class or HTML attribute had been used for this.
- In those alias texts there is a mix of English and of target language ("avoir"), where the latter is identified with the `<i>` tag -- a bad choice. It should have at least had the `lang` attribute. See next point:
- While often the `lang` HTML attribute is used to mark text that is in the target language, it sometimes is not. For instance, the table for French has "acculer" directly in a `td` tag without further indications (while a similar cell has "acculant" in a `span` tag that has a `lang="fr"` attribute).
- The Ancient Greek table sometimes lists alternative *endings* of conjugations, and without logic that is specific to Greek it is not possible to say these are only suffixes, and not full words. This is for example the case in the second aorist table.
- The Ancient Greek table sometimes lists alternatives for conjugations, separated by commas or slashes, where each alternative is in a separate tag (with `lang`). This means that the output structure should probably foresee an **array** of possible words.
- The Ancient Greek table sometimes lists optional *endings* in parentheses, and then these parentheses are not marked by `lang` attributes. However, in other cases the parentheses are part of the text node that has the `lang` attributes.
- The page for Ancient Greek has actually separate `table` elements for different tenses, while other pages have one overall table.
- The page for Ancient Greek has the tense itself is displayed in an element that is outside of the table. However, the `table` element has a CSS class name that includes the tense, so it can be extracted. Still this is not in harmony with how other tables are organised.
- The table for French has rows with "je (j')", "tu", ...etc, as if they are qualifiers, but they are actually hints on what the personal pronoun would be for the corresponding *person* and *number*. With some fuzzy logic they are excluded from the result, but again, this is not in harmony with how other tables are organised.
- The table for Latin has a first row that is not part of the structured data, but is the clickable line that allows the user the expand/collapse the rest of the table. Other pages have this clickable area outside of the table.
- The table for Ancient Greek as a last row that is not part of the structured data, but has a note about the dialect and a reference to an appendix.
- The Ancient Greek tables have a second section that spreads "active" and "middle/passive" voices over several columns, reusing columns that were previously used for *person* and *number*.
- The table for Arabic has a few (empty) `TD` cells in the headers for "passive voice", while logically those should be `TH` cells, just as in the table for "active voice".
- The table for Arabic starts with 13 columns (6 + 7), but then continues with 12, leaving the 13<sup>th</sup> undefined.

#### A script for those 4 languages

```js
// Function to get an element's text, marking italics with underscores, 
//    removing footnotes and extra white-space and optionally removing non-Latin text.
function clean(elem, latinOnly) {
    let txt = elem.textContent;
    const italic = elem.querySelector("i")?.textContent.trim(); 
    // Mark italics (assuming at most one word). latinOnly flag must be off:
    if (italic && !latinOnly) txt = txt.replaceAll(italic, "_" + italic + "_"); 
    // The parameter determines whether to remove non-Latin characters
    if (latinOnly) txt = txt.replace(/[^\x10-\xFF]+/gu, ""); // Remove non-Latin characters
    // Assume that a footnote appears as isolated, single digit
    return txt.replace(/(\s)\s*(\d\s+)?|—/gu, " ").trim();   // Remove footnotes, multiple whitespace
}

// Function to convert an HTML table to a matrix, duplicating data where col/rowspans occur
function toMatrix(table) {
    // Get a 2-letter lang attribute from anywhere in the whole table. To be used when
    //   a data cell does not have an element with a lang attribute.
    const defaultLang = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("[lang]"), elem => elem.getAttribute("lang"))
                             .find(lang => lang.length == 2) ?? "text";
    // Function to extract the content from a table cell, taking into account 
    //    tag (td/th), IPA class, lang, row/colspan attributes, and italics.
    // Returns an array of duplicated objects (to reflect colspan)
    function get(cell) {
        const length = +(cell.getAttribute("colspan") ?? 1);
        // Assume that the presence of italics means it is an alias:
        const hasAlias = !!cell.querySelector("i > span");
        // Assume that data is distinguished from qualifiers by use
        // of TD tag instead of TH tag
        const hasData = cell.tagName == "TD";
        const span = +(cell.getAttribute("rowspan") ?? 1);
        let content = {}; // Data will be represented in an object
        if (hasAlias) {
            content.alias = clean(cell);
        } else if (hasData) {
            const ipa = cell.querySelector(".IPA");
            if (ipa) content.ipa = clean(ipa);
            for (const version of cell.querySelectorAll("[lang]")) {
                const lang = version.getAttribute("lang");
                let cleanVersion = clean(version);
                // Check if this version is between parentheses, indicating it is an optional suffix
                //    This occurs in the Ancient Greek table, like with "ἀμφεκᾰ́λυψε(ν)"
                if (version.previousSibling?.textContent === "(") {
                    cleanVersion = (Array.isArray(content[lang]) ? content[lang].at(-1) : content[lang]) + cleanVersion;
                }
                // If there are multiple data for the same language: make an array;
                // If then also there is a parenthesis, assume the second version is an optional suffix for the first version
                content[lang] = lang in content
                    ? [].concat(content[lang], cleanVersion)
                    : cleanVersion;
            }
            // If there is no IPA class, nor lang attribute,
            // then assume that the whole text of this cell 
            // is text in the target language
            if (!Object.keys(content).length) {
                const version = clean(cell);
                content = version ? { [defaultLang]: version } : null;
            }
        } else {
            // It's a qualifier: assign a string (not object).
            // Only keep Latin character content.
            content = clean(cell, true);
        }
        // Return with the content also the rowspan
        return Array.from({length}, () => ({ content, span }));
    }

    let cells;
    const rows = [...table.rows];
    // Ignore first row if it is the clickable row to expand/collapse the rest of the table
    if (rows[0].cells[0].classList.contains("vsToggleElement")) rows.shift();
    // Ignore last row if it has notes
    if (rows.at(-1).cells[0].className.includes("-notes-")) rows.pop();
    return Array.from(rows, row => {
        // Get the current row, with colspans resolved into cells
        const buff = Array.from(row.cells, get).flat();
        // Integrate this row by taking into account the rowspans
        // of cells in previous row(s)
        cells = cells?.map(cell => --cell.span ? cell : buff.shift() ?? ({span:1})).concat(buff)
              ?? buff;
        // Now that rowspans have served their purpose, just retain
        // the content:
        return cells.map(cell => cell.content);
    });
}

// Function to extract a qualifier from the table elements CSS class list (Ancient Greek case)
function extractTense(table) {
    return table.className.match(/-conj-(\w+)/)?.[1];
}

// Function to convert matrix to the desired flat object. 
// Second argument can have key/value pair(s) when a table qualifier (like "number") needs to be replaced.
function toObject(matrix, qualifierReplacements) {
    const getDistinctCount = arr => arr.filter((s, i) => s !== arr[i-1]).length;
    const result = [];
    const tabQualifier = [];
    const colQualifiers = [];
    let hasGlobalQualifiers = false;
    let data = true;
    for (const [...row] of matrix) {
        // Find the column index where first data is found --
        // knowing that a data element is represented by an object 
        // while a qualifier is represented by a string data type
        const dataAt = row.findIndex(content => typeof content === "object");
        // Some heading rows have a TD element in first column (an inconsistency in the table for Arabic),
        // so only consider it data when in a non-first column
        if (dataAt < 1) { // No data; so this is a heading with only qualifier(s)
            // If the qualifier is present in the first column, it's a table qualifier (highest-level qualifier)
            if (row[0]) tabQualifier[0] = qualifierReplacements?.[row[0]] ?? row[0];
            // If the previous row had data, we enter a new section...
            if (data) {
                // When here we start with column qualifiers and not a table qualifier, consider 
                // those column qualifiers as global -- applying to all remaining sections
                if (!row[0]) hasGlobalQualifiers = true;
                // Reset the column-qualifiers when they are not global
                if (!hasGlobalQualifiers) colQualifiers.length = 0;
            }
            let distincts = getDistinctCount(colQualifiers.map(q => q?.at(-1)));
            // Reset column qualifiers when granularity decreases (this happens in the table for Ancient Greek)
            if (distincts > getDistinctCount(row)) colQualifiers.length = 0;
            // Only add column qualifiers when the addition would change the granularity.
            //    (this way we omit "je (j')" in the table for French)
            if (distincts != getDistinctCount(row)) {
                row.forEach((col, i) => (colQualifiers[i] ??= []).push(col));
            }
        } else { // Row with data
            // For sections that have no column headers, create one dummy column qualifier
            if (!colQualifiers.length) colQualifiers[dataAt] = [];
            const qualifier = [...tabQualifier, ...row.splice(0, dataAt)];
            // For each column with data, join it with the qualifiers
            colQualifiers.slice(dataAt).forEach((colQualifier, i) => {
                if (row[i]) {
                    const obj = {
                        // Because qualifiers may be collected as both table/column qualifiers
                        //    remove duplicates using Set
                        qualifier: [...new Set([...qualifier, ...colQualifier])],
                        data: {...row[i]}
                    };
                    // Don't add same object twice. This could happen when data & column qualifier 
                    // span multiple columns -- e.g. Ancient Greek infinitives
                    if (JSON.stringify(obj) != JSON.stringify(result.at(-1))) result.push(obj);
                }
            });
        }
        data = dataAt >= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

// Run the conversion on the HTML table in the current document
const table = document.querySelector("table");
const matrix = toMatrix(table);
const tense = extractTense(table);
const obj = toObject(matrix, { number: tense });
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">
        <span title="infinitif">infinitive</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="1">
        <small>simple</small>
      </th>
      <td>acculer </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">
        <small>compound</small>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6">
        <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2" >
        <span title="participe présent">present participle</span> or <span title="">gerund</span>
        <sup>1</sup>
      </th>
      <th colspan="1">
        <small>simple</small>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span lang="fr">
          <span>acculant</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span>
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɑ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1">
        <small>compound</small>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6">
        <i>
          <span>ayant</span>
        </i> + past participle
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2"></th>
      <th colspan="3" >singular </th>
      <th colspan="3" >plural </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th >first </th>
      <th >second </th>
      <th >third </th>
      <th >first </th>
      <th >second </th>
      <th >third </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th  colspan="2">
        <span title="indicatif">indicative</span>
      </th>
      <th >je (j’) </th>
      <th >tu </th>
      <th >il, elle, on </th>
      <th >nous </th>
      <th >vous </th>
      <th >ils, elles </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" >
        <small>(simple <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th >
        <span title="présent">present</span>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|s|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|s|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accules</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|s|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|p|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculons</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|p|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.le/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|p|pres|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculent</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th >
        <span title="imparfait">imperfect</span>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|s|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculais</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|s|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculais</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|s|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculait</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|p|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculions</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.ljɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|p|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculiez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lje/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|p|impf|indc-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculaient</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɛ/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" >
        <small>(compound <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th >
        <span title="passé composé">present perfect</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" >present indicative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th >
        <span title="plus-que-parfait">pluperfect</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" >imperfect indicative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th   colspan="2">
        <span title="subjonctif">subjunctive</span>
      </th>
      <th  >que je (j’) </th>
      <th  >que tu </th>
      <th  >qu’il, qu’elle </th>
      <th  >que nous </th>
      <th  >que vous </th>
      <th  >qu’ils, qu’elles </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2"  >
        <small>(simple <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th  >
        <span title="subjonctif présent">present</span>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|s|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|s|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accules</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|s|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|p|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculions</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.ljɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|p|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculiez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lje/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|p|pres|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculent</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th   rowspan="1">
        <span title="subjonctif imparfait">imperfect</span>
        <sup>2</sup>
      </th>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|s|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculasse</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.las/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|s|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculasses</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.las/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|s|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculât</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.la/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|p|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculassions</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.la.sjɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|p|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculassiez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.la.sje/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 3|p|impf|subj-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculassent</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.las/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2"  >
        <small>(compound <br>tenses) </small>
      </th>
      <th  >
        <span title="subjonctif passé">past</span>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" >present subjunctive of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th  >
        <span title="subjonctif plus-que-parfait">pluperfect</span>
        <sup>2</sup>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6" >imperfect subjunctive of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" >
        <span title="impératif">imperative</span>
      </th>
      <th >– </th>
      <th >
        <s>tu</s>
      </th>
      <th >– </th>
      <th >
        <s>nous</s>
      </th>
      <th >
        <s>vous</s>
      </th>
      <th >– </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th  colspan="2">
        <span title="">simple</span>
      </th>
      <td>— </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|s|impr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>accule</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.kyl/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>— </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 1|p|impr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculons</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.lɔ̃/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class=" 2|p|impr-form-of" lang="fr">
          <span>acculez</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span >
          <span class="IPA">/a.ky.le/</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>— </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th  colspan="2">
        <span title="">compound</span>
      </th>
      <td>— </td>
      <th >simple imperative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
      <td>— </td>
      <th >simple imperative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
      <th >simple imperative of <i>
          <span>avoir</span>
        </i> + past participle </th>
      <td>— </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Amazing, don't know how you do it so fast, I spent hours trying to wrap my head around it. Thank you.

Comment: Alas, now it's not working on the [Latin table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrenuntio#Latin) , I was eager to see if it would be general enough to work on all the complex Wikipedia tables. The Latin table looks pretty much exactly like the French table, I'm not sure what is wrong... It's only [capturing some stuff](https://imgur.com/a/VxYxn8E). Can you update the desc further so I can better understand what to tinker with? I also want to handle the [Ancient Greek table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CE%BC%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%80%CF%84%CF%89#Ancient_Greek)

Comment: I think it works on the greek table actually...

Comment: I added more text and more code comments. NB: I didn't check the other wiki pages you referenced in the above comments.

Comment: I updated the answer with a script that should work fine for the 4 language tables you have mentioned (French, Latin, Ancient Greek, Arabic).

Comment: I am realizing now just how there's no possible way to make a "generic table to JSON parser", I was hoping there was. Thank you for all your input!