# How to transform simple JSON matrix (rows and columns) to a record for each "data cell", with headers applied to each cell?

Tags: json, algorithm

This JSON matrix was generated via [this JS code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76219754/169992) against [this Latin verb conjugation table](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accedo#Latin) (click the "conjugation" bar to expand the table to see it on Wiktionary):

```
[
  [ "indicative"              , "indicative"              , "singular"                , "singular"                , "singular"                , "plural"                  , "plural"                  , "plural"                   ],
  [ "indicative"              , "indicative"              , "first"                   , "second"                  , "third"                   , "first"                   , "second"                  , "third"                    ],
  [ "active"                  , "present"                 , {"la":"accēdō"}           , {"la":"accēdis"}          , {"la":"accēdit"}          , {"la":"accēdimus"}        , {"la":"accēditis"}        , {"la":"accēdunt"}          ],
  [ "active"                  , "imperfect"               , {"la":"accēdēbam"}        , {"la":"accēdēbās"}        , {"la":"accēdēbat"}        , {"la":"accēdēbāmus"}      , {"la":"accēdēbātis"}      , {"la":"accēdēbant"}        ],
  [ "active"                  , "future"                  , {"la":"accēdam"}          , {"la":"accēdēs"}          , {"la":"accēdet"}          , {"la":"accēdēmus"}        , {"la":"accēdētis"}        , {"la":"accēdent"}          ],
  [ "active"                  , "perfect"                 , {"la":"accessī"}          , {"la":"accessistī"}       , {"la":"accessit"}         , {"la":"accessimus"}       , {"la":"accessistis"}      , {"la":"accessēre"}         ],
  [ "active"                  , "pluperfect"              , {"la":"accesseram"}       , {"la":"accesserās"}       , {"la":"accesserat"}       , {"la":"accesserāmus"}     , {"la":"accesserātis"}     , {"la":"accesserant"}       ],
  [ "active"                  , "future perfect"          , {"la":"accesserō"}        , {"la":"accesseris"}       , {"la":"accesserit"}       , {"la":"accesserimus"}     , {"la":"accesseritis"}     , {"la":"accesserint"}       ],
  [ "subjunctive"             , "subjunctive"             , "singular"                , "singular"                , "singular"                , "plural"                  , "plural"                  , "plural"                   ],
  [ "subjunctive"             , "subjunctive"             , "first"                   , "second"                  , "third"                   , "first"                   , "second"                  , "third"                    ],
  [ "active"                  , "present"                 , {"la":"accēdam"}          , {"la":"accēdās"}          , {"la":"accēdat"}          , {"la":"accēdāmus"}        , {"la":"accēdātis"}        , {"la":"accēdant"}          ],
  [ "active"                  , "imperfect"               , {"la":"accēderem"}        , {"la":"accēderēs"}        , {"la":"accēderet"}        , {"la":"accēderēmus"}      , {"la":"accēderētis"}      , {"la":"accēderent"}        ],
  [ "active"                  , "perfect"                 , {"la":"accesserim"}       , {"la":"accesserīs"}       , {"la":"accesserit"}       , {"la":"accesserīmus"}     , {"la":"accesserītis"}     , {"la":"accesserint"}       ],
  [ "active"                  , "pluperfect"              , {"la":"accessissem"}      , {"la":"accessissēs"}      , {"la":"accessisset"}      , {"la":"accessissēmus"}    , {"la":"accessissētis"}    , {"la":"accessissent"}      ],
  [ "imperative"              , "imperative"              , "singular"                , "singular"                , "singular"                , "plural"                  , "plural"                  , "plural"                   ],
  [ "imperative"              , "imperative"              , "first"                   , "second"                  , "third"                   , "first"                   , "second"                  , "third"                    ],
  [ "active"                  , "present"                 , null                      , {"la":"accēde"}           , null                      , null                      , {"la":"accēdite"}         , null                       ],
  [ "active"                  , "future"                  , null                      , {"la":"accēditō"}         , {"la":"accēditō"}         , null                      , {"la":"accēditōte"}       , {"la":"accēduntō"}         ],
  [ "non-finite forms"        , "non-finite forms"        , "active"                  , "active"                  , "active"                  , "passive"                 , "passive"                 , "passive"                  ],
  [ "non-finite forms"        , "non-finite forms"        , "present"                 , "perfect"                 , "future"                  , "present"                 , "perfect"                 , "future"                   ],
  [ "infinitives"             , "infinitives"             , {"la":"accēdere"}         , {"la":"accessisse"}       , {"la":"accessūrum esse"}  , null                      , null                      , null                       ],
  [ "participles"             , "participles"             , {"la":"accēdēns"}         , null                      , {"la":"accessūrus"}       , null                      , null                      , null                       ],
  [ "verbal nouns"            , "verbal nouns"            , "gerund"                  , "gerund"                  , "gerund"                  , "gerund"                  , "supine"                  , "supine"                   ],
  [ "verbal nouns"            , "verbal nouns"            , "genitive"                , "dative"                  , "accusative"              , "ablative"                , "accusative"              , "ablative"                 ],
  [ "verbal nouns"            , "verbal nouns"            , {"la":"accēdendī"}        , {"la":"accēdendō"}        , {"la":"accēdendum"}       , {"la":"accēdendō"}        , {"la":"accessum"}         , {"la":"accessū"}           ]
]
```

The JSON objects are cells with so-called "data", and the string cells area "header" cells. The null cells are just ignored.

Zoom out, and you'll see how the headers are somewhat creatively applied to the more right/bottom-directed cells.

[image]

1. You can have multiple layers of headers above data cells.
2. You can have multiple layers to the left of data cells.
3. The "above" header cells get reset occasionally, which you can tell because there are no data cells in that row (it's all strings).

The question is, how do you apply the header cells to the data cells, and output the final data cells with properties for each header, in an array? That is, just make each header be a boolean property, and if it has that property, set the boolean on that data cell to true.

So for example, the top-left-most data cell, when all the headers are added as boolean properties to it, would look like this:

```
{
  la: 'accēdō',
  active: true,
  present: true,
  indicative: true,
  singular: true,
  first: true,
}
```

Toward the middle on the bottom, we might have this record in the final array too:

```
{
  gerund: true,
  dative: true,
  la: 'accēdendō',
  'verbal nouns': true,
}
```

How can you move across and down this matrix, to properly apply these left and top "headers" to the data cells? I have been at this for days and haven't figured it out, tinkering with the code in many ways, but just throwing my hands up and trying to just hack and mutate the DOM to strip what I need. But given that we got to the point of isolating the complicated HTML table as a JSON matrix, maybe it is a simpler more straightforward problem to try and write a quick algorithm to apply the headers in the matrix to the data cells in the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the function you linked to, I made a few modifications to make it work for the matrix presented in the question.

To create keys with `true` as values, you could use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
// Function to convert matrix to the desired flat object. 
function toObject(matrix) {
    const result = [];
    const tabQualifier = [];
    const colQualifiers = [];
    let data = true;
    for (const [...row] of matrix) {
        // Find the column index where first data is found --
        // knowing that a data element is represented by an object 
        // while a qualifier is represented by a string data type
        const dataAt = row.findIndex(content => typeof content === "object");
        // Some heading rows have a TD element in first column (an inconsistency in the table for Arabic),
        // so only consider it data when in a non-first column
        if (dataAt < 1) { // No data; so this is a heading with only qualifier(s)
            // If the qualifier is present in the first column, it's a table qualifier (highest-level qualifier)
            if (row[0]) tabQualifier[0] = row[0];
            // If the previous row had data, we enter a new section... so reset the column-qualifiers
            if (data) colQualifiers.length = 0;
            row.forEach((col, i) => (colQualifiers[i] ??= []).push(col));
        } else { // Row with data
            // For sections that have no column headers, create one dummy column qualifier
            if (!colQualifiers.length) colQualifiers[dataAt] = [];
            const qualifier = [...tabQualifier, ...row.splice(0, dataAt)];
            // For each column with data, join it with the qualifiers
            colQualifiers.slice(dataAt).forEach((colQualifier, i) => {
                if (row[i]) {
                    result.push({
                        // Create keys with true as value for each of the relevant qualifiers
                        ...Object.fromEntries(Array.from([...qualifier, ...colQualifier], qual => [qual, true])),
                        ...row[i]
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        data = dataAt >= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

// The matrix as presented in the question
const matrix = [[ "indicative" , "indicative" , "singular" , "singular" , "singular" , "plural" , "plural" , "plural" ],[ "indicative" , "indicative" , "first" , "second" , "third" , "first" , "second" , "third" ],[ "active" , "present" , {"la":"accēdō"} , {"la":"accēdis"} , {"la":"accēdit"} , {"la":"accēdimus"} , {"la":"accēditis"} , {"la":"accēdunt"} ],[ "active" , "imperfect" , {"la":"accēdēbam"} , {"la":"accēdēbās"} , {"la":"accēdēbat"} , {"la":"accēdēbāmus"} , {"la":"accēdēbātis"} , {"la":"accēdēbant"} ],[ "active" , "future" , {"la":"accēdam"} , {"la":"accēdēs"} , {"la":"accēdet"} , {"la":"accēdēmus"} , {"la":"accēdētis"} , {"la":"accēdent"} ],[ "active" , "perfect" , {"la":"accessī"} , {"la":"accessistī"} , {"la":"accessit"} , {"la":"accessimus"} , {"la":"accessistis"} , {"la":"accessēre"} ],[ "active" , "pluperfect" , {"la":"accesseram"} , {"la":"accesserās"} , {"la":"accesserat"} , {"la":"accesserāmus"} , {"la":"accesserātis"} , {"la":"accesserant"} ],[ "active" , "future perfect" , {"la":"accesserō"} , {"la":"accesseris"} , {"la":"accesserit"} , {"la":"accesserimus"} , {"la":"accesseritis"} , {"la":"accesserint"} ],[ "subjunctive" , "subjunctive" , "singular" , "singular" , "singular" , "plural" , "plural" , "plural" ],[ "subjunctive" , "subjunctive" , "first" , "second" , "third" , "first" , "second" , "third" ],[ "active" , "present" , {"la":"accēdam"} , {"la":"accēdās"} , {"la":"accēdat"} , {"la":"accēdāmus"} , {"la":"accēdātis"} , {"la":"accēdant"} ],[ "active" , "imperfect" , {"la":"accēderem"} , {"la":"accēderēs"} , {"la":"accēderet"} , {"la":"accēderēmus"} , {"la":"accēderētis"} , {"la":"accēderent"} ],[ "active" , "perfect" , {"la":"accesserim"} , {"la":"accesserīs"} , {"la":"accesserit"} , {"la":"accesserīmus"} , {"la":"accesserītis"} , {"la":"accesserint"} ],[ "active" , "pluperfect" , {"la":"accessissem"} , {"la":"accessissēs"} , {"la":"accessisset"} , {"la":"accessissēmus"} , {"la":"accessissētis"} , {"la":"accessissent"} ],[ "imperative" , "imperative" , "singular" , "singular" , "singular" , "plural" , "plural" , "plural" ],[ "imperative" , "imperative" , "first" , "second" , "third" , "first" , "second" , "third" ],[ "active" , "present" , null , {"la":"accēde"} , null , null , {"la":"accēdite"} , null ],
[ "active" , "future" , null , {"la":"accēditō"} , {"la":"accēditō"} , null , {"la":"accēditōte"} , {"la":"accēduntō"} ],[ "non-finite forms" , "non-finite forms" , "active" , "active" , "active" , "passive" , "passive" , "passive" ],[ "non-finite forms" , "non-finite forms" , "present" , "perfect" , "future" , "present" , "perfect" , "future" ],[ "infinitives" , "infinitives" , {"la":"accēdere"} , {"la":"accessisse"} , {"la":"accessūrum esse"} , null , null , null ],[ "participles" , "participles" , {"la":"accēdēns"} , null , {"la":"accessūrus"} , null , null , null ],[ "verbal nouns" , "verbal nouns" , "gerund" , "gerund" , "gerund" , "gerund" , "supine" , "supine" ],[ "verbal nouns" , "verbal nouns" , "genitive" , "dative" , "accusative" , "ablative" , "accusative" , "ablative" ],[ "verbal nouns" , "verbal nouns" , {"la":"accēdendī"} , {"la":"accēdendō"} , {"la":"accēdendum"} , {"la":"accēdendō"} , {"la":"accessum"} , {"la":"accessū"} ]]
const obj = toObject(matrix);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I realise that this function will not solve *all* the matrices may have up your sleeve -- this just focuses on the one you presented in the question. I will however have another look at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76215584/5459839) hoping to provide a solution that would work for the matrices you get for the tables for French, Arabic, Latin and Ancient Greek.